2017 Bags 521r9 and 621r9
Bags 3,4&5
No instructions
Any help identifying?
https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg
Thanks

Hi BVR and welcome to Bricks.SE! It seems the uploading of the photo has hit a snag, can you please fix it? Refer to the [help] pages to see how editing works. Play well!
